# powershell convert csv column to datetime

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a CSV with a 'datetime' column in this format- "11/13/2022 4:30:00 PM".  How do I convert that string to a [datetime] type?

I apologize Im having a tough time with this one.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "this.csv" 
    
$formattedcsv = $CSV | Select-Object *, @{
        Name        = 'DateTime'
        Expression  = {
            (("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") -as [datetime])
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.datetime, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm", [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture)}`

Comment: This won't work because [1] for the month part you need `MM` (lowercase is for minutes) and [2] the example shows there is only one Hour digit (12-hour clock, so that needs to be `h`, not `HH` 24-hour clock) plus [3] it uses AM/PM designator you did not include

Comment: `import-csv this.csv | % { $_.Datetime = [datetime]$_.Datetime; $_ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you show ("11/13/2022 4:30:00 PM") uses the 12-hour clock and has AM/PM designators.

Use this instead:

```
$dateFormat = 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt'
$formattedcsv = $CSV | 
Select-Object *, 
              @{Name = 'DateTime'
                Expression = {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.datetime, $dateFormat, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)}
              } -ExcludeProperty datetime
```

Comment: Ah
Thank you Theo
I appreciate your time.

Comment: I get "property datetime already exists".  Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @js2010 Sorry, forgot about that.. Fixed now